# Rotate TImage inside a procedure (without using TTimer)

Tags: android, delphi, rotation, firemonkey

I was trying to make a simple animation inside a TButton procedure of a TImage rotating from a degree to another on Android using Delphi-Firemonkey (Berlin) like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
while Image1.RotationAngle < 360 do begin
Image1.RotationAngle := Image1.RotationAngle+1;
Image1.Repaint;
Sleep(1);
end;
end;
```

I've tried with and without Image1.Repaint but the animation simply does not work, but when using a TTimer it works perfectly. Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You are blocking the main thread. Use a timer so that the main thread remains responsive

Comment: Animation requires message processing. So don't block message processing. A better way to accomplish what you are attempting is to use FMX's [`TFloatAnimation`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Ani.TFloatAnimation) component to adjust the `RotationAngle` over time. See [Using FireMonkey Animation Effects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_FireMonkey_Animation_Effects).

Comment: What is the problem using the Timer ? (on the ButtonClick you can just Enable and Disable that Timer to start and/or stop the animation). As you say it works fine because it doesn't block the main thread.

Comment: Use a TFloatAnimation, set the property Rotation and start/end degree. It takes less than a minute and it's very easy

Answer (score 1):

add FMX.Ani to uses clause, and use TAnimator in button onlick event:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Image1.RotationAngle:=0;
 TAnimator.AnimateFloat(Image1,'RotationAngle',360,1,TAnimationType.InOut, TInterpolationType.Exponential );
end;
```

look into the docs for AnimateFloat, AnimateFloatWait, AnimateFloatDelay for detailed explanation of the params

Answer (score -2):

Don't use any `Sleep` calls in the main thread, you can rotate TImage without TTimer so:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sText: string;
begin
  Button1.Enabled := False;
  sText := Button1.Text;
  Button1.Text := 'Wait...';
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
  begin
    while Image1.RotationAngle < 360 do begin
      TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
      begin
        Image1.RotationAngle := Image1.RotationAngle + 2;
      end);
      Sleep(10);
    end;
    TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
    begin
      Button1.Text := sText;
      Button1.Enabled := True;
    end);
  end).Start;
end;
```

Second solution: Add `Anim: TFloatAnimation` to the Form:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
  public
    Anim: TFloatAnimation;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Anim.Enabled := False;
  Image1.RotationAngle := 0;
  Anim.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Anim := TFloatAnimation.Create(Self);
  Anim.Parent := Self;
  Anim.Duration := 1;
  Anim.StartValue := 0;
  Anim.StopValue := 360;
  Anim.PropertyName := 'Image1.RotationAngle';
end;
```

Comment: Terribly bad idea. For instance, imagine pressing the button a few more times.....

Comment: Yes, previous edition of answer was contain example with comment that this is a bad idea